# Using TInvokeableVariantType to create dynamic procedure

Tags: delphi

Using `TInvokeableVariantType` it's possible to create custom variant type with dynamic *methods*:

```
var
    somevariant: Variant;

somevariant.Method();
```

But is it possible to invoke variant variable itself? Delphi 2007 compiler doesn't even compile this:

```
var
    somevariant: Variant;

somevariant();
```

I'm not surprised with this but I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything and it's not possible in Delphi or FPC to create dynamic procedure without needing to invoke it as a method of variant?

Comment: You should use a procedural type no?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The thing is in `TInvokeableVariantType.DoProcedure` you can act more dynamically that in normal procedure. Yes you could invoke normal procedure by using procedural type. But at least in Delphi 2007 you cannot do `proceduralTypeVar := somevariant.Method;`.

Comment: I think readers may be wondering, what do you mean by "invoke variant variable itself"?  "Invoke" usually refers to an action some kind of object could carry out.  How would a variant carry out itself?

Answer (score 2):

A `Variant` is not an invokable data type by itself.  It is a container of data which may be invokable (a COM object or TInvokeableVariantType object), so you have to dereference the `Variant` using the `.` operator to access the data and tell the compiler which invokable operations you want to perform on the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "dereference" the `Variant`?